# Sybase dataadd time where time added is the difference of 2 times

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have a sybase database and would like to create a new bigdatetimefield by adding time to a current bigdatetimefield

for example

```
I have a date1 field =   8/31/2015 2:23:49.529000 PM    
I have a date2 field  =    8/31/2015 7:23:49.529000 AM
I have a mainDate field =  8/31/2015 2:24:46.112000 PM
```

I would like to make a new field that is the mainDate field minus the difference in time between the date1 field and the date2 field

So in this case the new filed would be  8/31/2015 2:24:46.112000 PM  - (8/31/2015 2:23:49.529000 PM - 8/31/2015 7:23:49.529000 AM)

Any idea how to do that in sybase?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT new_dt = DATEADD(ss, datediff(ss,date1,date2),mainDate)
FROM  my_table
```

That's only accurate to seconds though.  You can use millisecond or microsecond.